# Make a filter by user firstname or lastname or company name?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this query:

```
  public function getResultCommentsWithArticle($comment,$name,$article_title,$orderBy){
        $default_language = Languages::where('default',1)->first();
        $default_language_id = $default_language->id;
        $comments = ArticleComments::orderBy($orderBy,'desc')
                    ->with(['user', 'article'])
                    ->whereHas('article.translations', function($q)
                        use($default_language_id,$article_title) {

                        $q->where('language_id', $default_language_id)
                        ->where('title','like','%' . $article_title . '%');
                    })->where('comment','like','%' . $comment . '%')->paginate(10);

        return $comments;
      }
```

I have this relationships:

user:

```
  public function personal_user()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('App\Models\PersonalUser', 'userable');
    }

    public function business_user()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('App\Models\BusinessUser', 'userable');
    }
```

When i get text name from `$name`, i want to check if that text exist in `user->personal_user->first_name` OR in `user->personal_user->last_name` OR in `user->business_user->company_name`, because im making a filter. Any suggestion how can i do that?

Comment: `if ( user->personal_user->first_name === $name || user->personal_user->last_name === $name || user->business_user->company_name === $name ) { echo 'found'; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try if this works for you

```
$comments = ArticleComments::orderBy($orderBy, 'desc')
            ->with([
                'article',
                'user' => function ($user) use ($name) {
                    $user->whereHas('personal_user', function ($personalUser) use ($name) {
                        $personalUser->where(function ($q) use ($name) {
                            $q->orwhere('first_name', 'like', '%' . $name . '%')
                                ->orwhere('last_name', 'like', '%' . $name . '%');
                        });
                    })->whereHas('business_user', function ($businessUser) use ($name) {
                        $businessUser->where(function ($q) use ($name) {
                            $q->orwhere('company_name', 'like', '%' . $name . '%');
                        });
                    });
                }
            ])->whereHas('article.translations', function ($q) use ($default_language_id, $article_title) {
                $q->where('language_id', $default_language_id)
                    ->where('title', 'like', '%' . $article_title . '%');
            })->where('comment', 'like', '%' . $comment . '%')->paginate(10);

        return $comments;
```